# combination numbers induction proof

Tags: combinatorics, induction

> Consider numbers $n \geq r \geq 1$ where $n,r \in \mathbb{Z} $, prove the following:
>   $$\binom {r}{r} + \binom {r+1}{r}...+ \binom n r = \binom {n+1}{r+1}$$

Only thing I know is that if I choose to use induction using n  choosing the base case n = r = 1 is not the way to go.

I also tried to rewrite it into the following

$$1 + \sum_{i=r+1}^n \binom i r = \binom {n+1}{r+1}$$ but that didn't really help me all that much.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "choosing the base case $n=r=1$ is not..."!!

Comment: [Hockey Stick identity](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Combinatorial_identity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
\binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r+1} = \binom{n+1}{r+1}
$$
Therefore repeatedly applying this in reverse,
$$
\begin{split}
\binom{n+1}{r+1}
 &= \binom{n}{r} + \binom{n}{r+1} \\
 &= \binom{n}{r} + \binom{n-1}{r} + \binom{n-1}{r+1} \\
 &= \binom{n}{r} + \binom{n-1}{r} + \binom{n-2}{r} + \binom{n-2}{r+1}
\end{split}
$$
can you finish this?

Answer (score 1):

Base case $n=r$. Thus $$\sum_{k=r}^{n=r}\binom{k}{r}=1=\binom{r+1}{r+1}$$
For the inductive case suppose, for some $i\in\mathbb{N}\; :\; i>r$, $$\sum_r^{i}\binom{k}{r}=\binom{i+1}{r+1}$$ So $$\sum_r^{i+1}\binom{k}{r}=\Biggl(\sum_r^{i}\binom{k}{r}\Biggr)+\binom{i+1}{r}=\binom{i+1}{r+1}+\binom{i+1}{r}$$ $$=\frac{(i+1)!}{(r+1)!(i-r)!}+\frac{(i+1)!}{r!(i+1-r)!}=\frac{(i+1)!(i+1-r)}{(r+1)!(i+1-r)!}+\frac{(i+1)!(r+1)}{(r+1)!(i+1-r)!}=\frac{(i+2)!}{(r+1)!(i+1-r)!}=\binom{i+2}{r+1}$$
Which proves the statement since the base case is already proven.

This is by the way known as the Hockey-Stick Identity.

Answer (score 0):

Idea induction for n and 
$$
\\{n+1 \choose k+1}={n\choose k+1}+{n\choose k}
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Rewrite *Pascal's relation* as
$$\binom{r+i}r=\binom{r+i+1}{r+1}-\binom{r+i}{r+1}$$
and sum these relations w.r.t. $i$  to obtain a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 0):

given that:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=^aC_b=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$$
you could try and re-write the summation this way as there will always be an $r!$ common term on the bottom, so try and write it all as one fraction and see where this goes